# Does SQLAlchemy support H2DB?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, h2

Does SQLAlchemy support H2 db? I'm using pyramid and would like to connect to H2 db database. If using postgres dialect, I'm getting error like the following:

```
File "/Users/homecamera/gotocamera/hcadmin/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 871, in initialize
super(PGDialect, self).initialize(connection)
File "/Users/homecamera/gotocamera/hcadmin/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 181, in initialize
self.get_isolation_level(connection.connection)
File "/Users/homecamera/gotocamera/hcadmin/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py", line 910, in get_isolation_level
cursor.execute('show transaction isolation level')
ProgrammingError: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT "; expected "TOP, LIMIT, DISTINCT, ALL, *, NOT, EXISTS"; SQL statement:
show transaction isolation level [42001-140]
DETAIL:  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT "; expected "TOP, LIMIT, DISTINCT, ALL, *, NOT, EXISTS"; SQL statement:
show transaction isolation level [42001-140]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there's no official support for either HSQLDB dialects or native H2 dialect.
Using Postgres dialect with H2 (without using HSQLDB) would definitely result in error you're getting.

You might have better luck trying [sqlalchemy-jython](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-jython/) and using H2 dialect.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm currently connecting to H2 with direct SQL using psycopg.

Comment: @carbotex, could you, please, clarify how you are doing that? I'm struggling to get psycopg to connect to an in-memory database. I can't get it to pass the authentication step. Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stumbles over this again, I tried to get this running (as an alternative to sqlite) and it only partially works, and the only driver that works is pg8000.

With the server running using:

```
nohup java -cp /opt/h2/bin/h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server -pg -pgAllowOthers -pgPort 5435 -baseDir /opt/h2-data &
```

This code works in sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://sa:sa@localhost:5435/main')
engine.execute("SELECT 1")
```

However this code throws an exception: 
    from sqlalchemy_utils import create_database
    create_database('postgresql+pg8000://sa:sa@localhost:5435/main')

Exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pg8000.core.ProgrammingError) ('ERROR', 
'HY000', 'General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: output binary 
format is undefined" [50000-196]', 'org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General
error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: output binary format is undefined"
[50000-196]') [SQL: 'select version()']
```